# Efficient SQL statement to encode text for NLP locutions

Tags: regex, string, postgresql, query-optimization, substring

### Background

A locution is a noun-phrase consisting of at least two words, such as:

- black olive
- hot pepper sauce
- rose finn apple potato

The separate words *black* and *olive* are an adjective (*black* - JJ) and a noun (*olive* - NN). However, humans know that *black olive* is a noun (that differentiates it from, say, a *green olive*).

The problem here is how to most efficiently transform a list of normalized ingredient names (such as the list above) into a specific format for a natural language processor (NLP).

### Example Data

The table can be created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE ingredient_name (
  id bigserial NOT NULL, -- Uniquely identifies the ingredient.
  label character varying(30) NOT NULL
);
```

The following SQL statements show actual database records:

```
insert into ingredient_name (label) values ('alfalfa sprout');
insert into ingredient_name (label) values ('almond extract');
insert into ingredient_name (label) values ('concentrated apple juice');
insert into ingredient_name (label) values ('black-eyed pea');
insert into ingredient_name (label) values ('rose finn apple potato');
```

### Data Format

The general format is:

```
lexeme1_lexeme2_<lexemeN> lexeme1_lexeme2_lexemeN NN
```

Given the list of words above, the NLP expects:

```
black_<olive> black_olive NN
hot_pepper_<sauce> hot_pepper_sauce NN
rose_finn_apple_<potato> rose_finn_apple_potato NN
```

The database has a table (`recipe.ingredient_name`) and a column (`label`). The labels are normalized (e.g., single space, lower case).

### SQL Statement

The code that produces the expected results:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ingredient_locutions_vw AS 
SELECT
  t.id,
   -- Replace spaces with underscores
  translate( t.prefix, ' ', '_' )
  || '<' || t.suffix || '>' || ' ' ||
  translate( t.label, ' ', '_' )
  || ' NN' AS locution_nlp
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,

    -- Ingredient name
    label,

    -- All words except the last word
    left( label, abs( strpos( reverse( label ), ' ' ) - length( label ) ) + 1 ) AS prefix,

    -- Just the last word
    substr( label,
       length( label ) - strpos( reverse( label ), ' ' ) + 2
    ) AS suffix
  FROM
    ingredient_name
  WHERE
    -- Limit set to ingredient names having at least one space
    strpos( label, ' ' ) > 0
) AS t;
```

### Question

What is a more efficient (or elegant) way to split the `prefix` (all words except the first) and `suffix` (just the last word) in the above code?

The system is PostgreSQL 9.1.

Thank you!

Comment: It appears you have the "sentences" stored inside space-separated strings. Could you add The table definitions + some sample data ? Also: is the output appears to be intended to be fed into an external NLP-program?

Comment: Yes. The output is passed (indirectly) to NLP software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ingredient_locutions_vw AS 
SELECT
    t.id,
    format('%s_<%s> %s NN', 
        array_to_string(t.prefix, '_'), 
        t.suffix, 
        array_to_string(t.label, '_')
    ) AS locution_nlp
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,

        -- Ingredient name
        label,

        -- All words except the last word
        label[1:array_length(label, 1) - 1] AS prefix,

        -- Just the last word
        label[array_length(label, 1)] AS suffix
    FROM (
        select id, string_to_array(label, ' ') as label
        from ingredient_name
    ) s
    WHERE
    -- Limit set to ingredient names having at least one space
    array_length(label, 1) > 1
) AS t;
```

---

```
select * from ingredient_locutions_vw ;
 id |                      locution_nlp                      
----+--------------------------------------------------------
  1 | alfalfa_<sprout> alfalfa_sprout NN
  2 | almond_<extract> almond_extract NN
  3 | concentrated_apple_<juice> concentrated_apple_juice NN
  4 | black-eyed_<pea> black-eyed_pea NN
  5 | rose_finn_apple_<potato> rose_finn_apple_potato NN
(5 rows)
```

Comment: @DaveJarvis Ok changed it to use label as text.

Comment: @DaveJarvis Since this is 9.1 I added a bit more elegance with the format function.

Comment: Nice! One minor error: `alfalfa<sprout>` must be `alfalfa_<sprout>`. I fixed the code, but haven't tested it.

Comment: @DaveJarvis Corrected. That was because your own view also misses the underscore before the `<` and I considered safer to follow the code in instead of the enunciated :).